# How do you algebraically solve $x=\cos(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have also been told it's impossible. If so, how?

Comment: Try to invert cosine, then you see you've only shifted the problem to be $x = \arrcos{x}$. The Taylor series of cosine has infinite terms so you cant use that either.

Comment: It can't be solved algebraically because $\cos$ is not an algebraic function.